# Future events times and Lévy processes

Tags: stochastic-processes, stopping-times, levy-processes

If I am at time $t$ and I know that in the future, at time $t+h$ a process $X_s$ will jump by a random quantity, can $X_s$ be a Lévy process? ($X_s$ jumps before and after $t+h$ at random times)

If **not** what properties of Levy processes does it violate?

If **yes** how does the filtration of time $t$ relates to the filtration of time $t+h$? 
Shouldn't the knowledge of jump time  $t+h$ be included only in the filtrations $\mathcal{F}_w$ for $w\geq t+h$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not a Lévy process because Lévy processes must have the property (which is almost equivalent to a definition(*)) to be continuous in probability, in other words almost surely at a time s (for example t+h) the paths of the process are continuous. As you know that the process is almost surly discontinuous your process is not Lévy.

For a reference look at the first chapter of Protter's book on stochastic calculus.

Best regards
Edit :
(*)Yo have to independent and stationary increments hypotheses to get a Lévy process.

Comment: The important part "as you know the process is almost surely discontinuous" follows from the assumption that the jump at time $t+h$ has probability, yes? @TheBridge

Comment: @ olorun : if a process jumps at fixed time almost surely it's not continuos in probability, this is what I meant. Best regards.